# Передача данных в новую форму JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gui

**Доброго времени суток!**
Столкнулся с вопросом передачи необходимых данных в новую форму.
Раньше тоже сталкивался с таким но я тогда сделал костыль по типу загрузить нужное в текстовый файл и в новой форме в методе `Initiallize` загружал их.

Но все же хочу научится делать это правильно.
Так что ищу способ например вызвать метод или конструктор контроллера при загрузке новой формы или другой более практичный метод подгрузки данных в новую форму со старой.
Хотелось бы увидеть наглядный пример или источник где раскрывается данная тема.

*Заранее благодарен!*

Comment: Возможно поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Comment: @post_zeew отлично! Это то что нужно, спасибо большое))